# How to extract the maximum number using bubble sort in java?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and I have a problem in finding the maximum number in an integer array using bubble sort

This is how my Program is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Bubblesorting
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    void ascendingOrder()
    {
        int[] no=new int[10];
        System.out.println("ENTER 10 NUMBERS");
        for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
        {
            no[i]=sc.nextInt();
            for(int j=0;j<no.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=j;k<no.length-1;k++)
                {
                    if(no[j]<no[k+1])
                    {
                        int t=no[k+1];
                        no[k+1]=no[j];
                        no[j]=t;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(no[no.length]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _using bubblesort_?

Comment: `no[no.length]` will throw an exception (out of bounds) because it's `no[10]` and  `no` is from 0 to 9.

Comment: I think you should at first fill the array and at least sort it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sort an array in order to get the maximum number in it. Simply iterate once over the array updating the maximum value found so far. Something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Bubblesorting
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    void ascendingOrder()
    {
        int[] no=new int[10];
        System.out.println("ENTER 10 NUMBERS");
        for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
        {
            no[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        int maxv = no[0];
        for (int i =0;i<10;++i) {
            if (no[i] > maxv) {
                maxv = no[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxv);
    }
}
```

Still if you insist that you have to sort the array first - separate the read from the sorting logic. You should first read all the numbers and then sort the whole array. Also keep in mind arrays in most programming languages are 0 indexed thus valid indices for no are `0` to `no.length-1` so you should `System.out.println(no[no.length - 1]);` instead of `System.out.println(no[no.length]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition should be check greater then condition like `if(no[j]>no[k+1])`.

And also do change in sysout

```
System.out.println(no[no.length-1]);
```

Your code should something like

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      void ascendingOrder()
        {
            int[] no=new int[10];
            System.out.println("ENTER 10 NUMBERS");
            for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
            {
                no[i]=sc.nextInt();
                for(int j=0;j<no.length;j++)
                {
                    for(int k=j;k<no.length-1;k++)
                    {
                        if(no[j]>no[k+1])
                        {
                            int t=no[k+1];
                            no[k+1]=no[j];
                            no[j]=t;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(no[no.length-1]);
        }
```